# Microsoft Bot Famework - Webchat - event

Tags: botframework, web-chat

Using botframework V4 - NodeJS - React Webchat V4

I am trying to send a message to bot, similar to a button click event in adaptive card. whenever a button is clicked in adaptive card i can see an event similar to below getting generated in the webchat

```
  type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_POST_BACK',
  payload: { value: {mytext: "myvalue"} }
```

Tried to send below dispatch message from the webchat on a custom button click, most of the time it is working and sometimes it wont send the message to bot. So i would like to know if this is the right approach or not. I can use WEB_CHAT/SEND_MESSAGE similar to below example

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/d.post-activity-event

but this is displaying the message on the chat window, i don't want to display the message that is sent to bot in my chat window.

```
this.store.dispatch({
  type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_POST_BACK',
  payload: { value: {buttonClick: "mytext", scanText: myvalue} }
});
```

Comment: Can you please edit and include all of the “store” code? Even better would be all of your web chat code (not including any keys / tokens).

Comment: Yes, that is the correct syntax for sending a `postBack` from Web Chat to your bot. It shouldn't display any messages. You just need to decide when it should dispatch that action and how / when you want to capture the payload when it passes thru to your bot.